# Selective screenshot using <Super>+Button1 is Overlayed with blue color

Tags: 11.04, compiz, screenshot

The Screen shot plugin enabled from Compiz Config Settings Manager doesn't work properly. The screen shots of the selected areas get overshadowed with blue color..

Not as clear of a screen shot as I would get in previous Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Bump.Annoying problem for a great simple tool.

Comment: +1 ... Following this question closely and waiting for a solution...

Answer (score 6):

This is a known bug in Compiz: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/771875

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry you are getting this problem, but as tshirtman points out, it is a known bug.
What you should probably do is install shutter or lookit and use them for taking screenshots.

In both applications you can even use the same (or at least a similar) shortcut.

*P.S. I will add further instructions later.*

Comment: had to dig through a lot of crud on google just to find the name of a program that could take selective screenshots. thanks for suggesting 'shutter'. works great!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the [`Take Screenshot`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-screenshot) tool, which is installed by default. When you run this from the dash you can choose the option to capture a selected area.

[image: Bildschirmfoto aufnehmen]

Shortcuts are <kbd>Print</kbd> for the whole screen and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> for the active window.

You can select an area to capture directly with the command `gnome-screenshot -a` after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. You could create a shortcut for this (i. e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>), but as I try this here it doesn't seem to work fluently - sometimes I have to press for a second or two. (Problem described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12823/how-to-define-a-shortcut-key-to-grab-part-of-the-screen))

---

In *Ubuntu 12.04 Precise* the `Screenshot` section in `System Settings` → `Keyboard` → `Shortcuts` became enhanced. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> to take a screenshot of a selected area. This works without any problems.

Comment: Even though this is a straight forward method or an alternative, still the Compiz screenshot is simple and quick. I don't like to discard it anyways.

Comment: In 12.04 this is as simple and quick like Compiz: Just press Shift+Print. You don't need to install or configure anything before.

Comment: It is quite a long time now. Still I had to move back to 11.04 for sometime. Now I have fully into 12.04. Yes, It is a good modification for 12.04 version. It is not a straight away drag, first the cross-hair need to appear and then we drag or is there another way to do that !!

Answer (score 0):

Unity is the reason for me. When I disable Unity Panel or when I switch to Ubuntu Classic, the screenshot by +Button1 works superb.

The Ubuntu Unity Plugin is a real problem that serves to make a blue overlay on screen shots. It has some kind of conflict with Screenshot feature.

Also I feel that Avant Window Navigator (AWN) is real good replacement for Unity. Now I can take screenshots with Inbuilt compiz feature.